# Association that don't look much sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I need a little help to understand this association types.

I have 2 models (item_type and item)

item_type it's just acting like a category and have only one field (title)

## Table structure:

item_type:

- id
- title
- created_at
- updated_at

item:

- id
- item_type_id
- title
- price
- other irrelevant fields..

So, basicly I'm trying to do a simple association between this models.

```
class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :item_type
end
```

I have created an item and save it, but when I'm fetching it to show, it should display the item_type.title instead of just item_type.id, right?

I've readed about that belongs_to always goes on the table that has the foreign_key, but in this case, it doesn't make much sense for me.. and even inverting the relationships, putting the has_one on the ItemType class and the belongs_to to the Item class, either this way works.

In the controller code I have:

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id], :include => 'item_type')
end
```

And the view, should be visible to see the relationship created just with

```
<%= debug @item %>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing a proper id to the show method? E.g. `http://localhost/item/show/24` or `show?id=24`? Have you assigned an ItemType to the Item when creating it, e.g. `a = Item.new(:title => "item title", :price => 42, :type => ItemType.new(:title => "item type")); a.save!` ?

Comment: yep, I have just edited right now, can you see the edit comment?

Comment: oh forget it.. I removed the include parameter and it's working fine. Just using @item.item_type.title on the view to display it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i remember you need to put belongs_to in the model who contain the foreign key, in your example :

```
class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item_type
end
```

See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: yup! I knew that.. I was just missing the right way to display the desired data on the view side. I'm going to consider this answer as correct one. Thank you.